# Border Radius does not fully cover image

Tags: html, css

[image: 1]

```css
.fotoPerfil{
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -6em;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img class="fotoPerfil" src="./img/manu.png">
    </div>
```

Hello, I have a little problem with this image, idk if you can see it but the border does not fully cover part of the pic, there is a thin space at the top of the image.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` or the other `box-sizing: content-box` might do the trick

Comment: Add these properties to the parent and remove this from <img> and make the width 100% to the image will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I made the border red and added a random photo from google images to help make this snippet a little more visual. This is how I would go about making the photo inside the border and having a container to make the whole thing position absolute if thats still needed for something.

```css
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
.fotoPerfil {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fotoPerfil img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center fotoPerfil">
    <img src="https://i.natgeofe.com/k/830b5d15-92db-429f-a80a-cc89b5700af5/mt-everest.jpg?w=636&h=437">
  </div>
</div>
```